# How to plot a (sophisticated) stacked barplot in ggplot2, without complicated manual data aggregation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a (facetted) stacked barplot where the X-Axis is in percent. Also the Frequency labels are displayed within the bars.

After quite some work and viewing many different questions on stackoverflow, I found a solution on how to solve this with ggplot2. However, I don't do it directly with ggplot2, I manually aggregate my data with a table call. And I do this manual aggregation in a complicated way and also calculate the percent values manually with temp variables (see source code comment "manually aggregate data").

How can I do the same plot, but in a nicer way without the manual and complicated data aggregation?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

library(gridExtra)
library(plyr)

##
##  Random Data
##
fact1 <- factor(floor(runif(1000, 1,6)),
                      labels = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"))

fact2 <- factor(floor(runif(1000, 1,6)),
                      labels = c("g1","g2", "g3", "g4", "g5"))

##
##  STACKED BAR PLOT that scales x-axis to 100%
##

## manually aggregate data
##
mytable <- as.data.frame(table(fact1, fact2))

colnames(mytable) <- c("caseStudyID", "Group", "Freq")

mytable$total <- sapply(mytable$caseStudyID,
                        function(caseID) sum(subset(mytable, caseStudyID == caseID)$Freq))

mytable$percent <- round((mytable$Freq/mytable$total)*100,2)

mytable2 <- ddply(mytable, .(caseStudyID), transform, pos = cumsum(percent) - 0.5*percent)


## all case studies in one plot (SCALED TO 100%)

p1 <- ggplot(mytable2, aes(x=caseStudyID, y=percent, fill=Group)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.4, "cm")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = sapply(Freq, function(x) ifelse(x>0, x, NA)), y = pos), size = 3) # the ifelse guards against printing labels with "0" within a bar


print(p1)
```

..
[image]

Comment: PS: it might take me up to 14 hours to answer to comments or react in any way, as I am in a different time zone compare to most SO users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you make the data:

```
fact1 <- factor(floor(runif(1000, 1,6)),
                  labels = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"))

fact2 <- factor(floor(runif(1000, 1,6)),
                  labels = c("g1","g2", "g3", "g4", "g5"))

dat = data.frame(caseStudyID=fact1, Group=fact2)
```

You can automate making an unlabeled graph of the kind that you want with `position_fill`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(caseStudyID, fill=Group)) + geom_bar(position="fill")
```

[image: unlabeled graph]

I don't know if there's a way to generate the text labels automatically. The positions and counts from the stacked graph are accessible with `ggplot_build`, if you want to use what ggplot calculates instead of doing it separately.

```
p = ggplot(dat, aes(caseStudyID, fill=Group)) + geom_bar(position="fill")
ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
```

That will return a dataframe with (among other things), `count`, `x`, `y`, `ymin`, and `ymax` variables that can be used to create positioned labels.

If you want the labels vertically centered in each category, first make a column with values halfway between `ymin` and `ymax`.

```
freq = ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
freq$y_pos = (freq$ymin + freq$ymax) / 2
```

Then add the labels to the graph with `annotate`.

```
p + annotate(x=freq$x, y=freq$y_pos, label=freq$count, geom="text", size=3)
```

[image: labeled]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the distribution of case study ID's in each group as single vector, you could use the [sjp.stackfrq](https://rpubs.com/sjPlot/sjpstackfrq) function from the sjPlot-package.

```
A <- floor(runif(1000, 1,6))
B <- floor(runif(1000, 1,6))
C <- floor(runif(1000, 1,6))
D <- floor(runif(1000, 1,6))
E <- floor(runif(1000, 1,6))

mydf <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
sjp.stackfrq(mydf, legendLabels = c("g1","g2", "g3", "g4", "g5"))
```

[image]

The function offers many parameters to easily customize plot appearance (labelling, size and colors etc.).