# Showing percentage in bars in ggplot

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, bar-chart, percentage

I have a dataset with binary variables like the one below.

```
M4 = matrix(sample(1:2,20*5, replace=TRUE),20,5)
M4 <- as.data.frame(M4)
M4$id <- 1:20
```

I have produced a stacked bar plot using the code below

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
M5 <- melt(M4, id="id")
M5$value <- as.factor(M5$value)
ggplot(M5, aes(x = variable)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = value), position = 'fill') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

Now I want the percentage for each field in each bar to be displayed in the graph, so that each bar reach 100%. I have tried [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231124/how-to-draw-stacked-bars-in-ggplot2-that-show-percentages-based-on-group), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011266/label-selected-percentage-values-inside-stacked-bar-plot-ggplot2), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386005/r-stacked-percentage-bar-plot-with-percentage-of-binary-factor-and-labels-with) and several similar questions, but I can't find any example that fits my situation. How can I manage this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `sjp.stackfrq` function from the [sjPlot-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/index.html) (see [examples here](http://rpubs.com/sjPlot/sjpstackfrq)).

```
M4 = matrix(sample(1:2,20*5, replace=TRUE),20,5)
M4 <- as.data.frame(M4)
sjp.stackfrq(M4)
# alternative colors: sjp.stackfrq(M4, barColor = c("aquamarine4", "brown3"))
```

[image]

Plot appearance can be custzomized with various parameters...

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
test <- ggplot(M5, aes(x = variable, fill = value, position = 'fill')) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  stat_bin(aes(label=paste("n = ",..count..)), vjust=1, geom="text")
test
```

[image]

EDITED: to give percentages and using the `scale`s package:

```
require(scales)
test <- ggplot(M5, aes(x = variable, fill = value, position = 'fill')) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  stat_bin(aes(label = paste("n = ", scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)))), vjust=1, geom="text")
test
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like precentage to me, you probably want something like `paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")` (instead of `paste("n = ",..count..)`)

Comment: Many thanks for your help!
Worked out beautifully to get the counts, but I was looking for the percentage; perhaps you can give some advice on that?
Would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: @Arenburg: That code returns the cumulative percentage for the entire graph, instead of each bar. In other words, all the fields in all bars together add up to 100%, while I need each bar to add up to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the usage of the implicit information that is created by ggplot itself, as described in this post:

[using the ggplot_build() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518741/how-to-plot-a-sophisticated-stacked-barplot-in-ggplot2-without-complicated-ma/25524236#25524236)

From my point of view this provides a lot of opportunities to finally control the appearance of a ggplot chart.

Hope this helps somehow

Tom