# Overlay percentage in barplot with correct scale with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay percentages to a barplot with `ggplot`. I have tried to approaches which have failed:

1. Using geom_text:

   ```
   p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(data[[variable1]]) ), environment = environment() )
   p <- p + geom_bar(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)), position = modo)
   p <- p + geom_text( aes(labels = ..count../sum(..count..)) , vjust = -0.2)
   p <- p + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
   ```

I get the error message:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'count' not found

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620262/showing-percentage-in-bars-in-ggplot), I tried the stat_bin function, but the scale gets messed up, and I lost the bars (based on the new scale, I guess they still exist but are just not visible):

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(data[[variable1]]) ), environment = environment() )
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)), position = modo)
p <- p + stat_bin( aes(label = ..count../sum(..count..) ) , vjust = -0.2, geom ="text" )
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

This is what I get:

[image: This is what I get]

Any clues on how to solve this?

Comment: I can't test if it's the cause of your problem, but you really should ditch using `environment` and just use `aes_string()`.

Comment: I am using this code inside a function. Using 'environment = environment()' is apparently the only way for avoiding a bug that avoids some variables to be seen. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r

Comment: The accepted answer there is bad. Read some of the other answers. You should basically never, ever be referring to variables inside `aes()` with anything other than bare names. If you need to programmatically choose variables to plot that is what `aes_string()` is for.

Comment: I wrote a long comment on that answer that hopefully clarifies things somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here:

I had to map the y values. I also had to multiply label values by 100 in order to have consistent percentages.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(data[[variable1]]) ), environment = environment() )
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)), position = modo)
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
p <- p + stat_bin( aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..), label = paste(  round( 100 * ..count../sum(..count..)), "%" ) ), vjust = -0.2, geom ="text" )
```